# How do I merge two laravel projects into one?

Tags: php, laravel, merge

So in my /var/www folder I have two folders with projects developed with Laravel. And now I want them to be one project, I mean, I placed project A folder inside project B folder, and I want project A to become part of B, so that from virtualhost it would be accessible like b/a/home.php. But for now these two projects have different vendor folders, composer settings, two route.php and .env files, and so on. What could be the solution to my problem (preferably without merging files themself, like creating one routes.php with all the routes from both projects)? Would highly appreciate any possible help!

Comment: After just moving A into B and typing address http://b/a/public/index.php I get NotFoundHttpException

Comment: Just a suggestion but When I migrated an Lavavel App into another I used a Laravel package called L5 modular. It creates modules meaning an 'app' can have its own controllers models and views but still exist in one Laravel installation. Just bare in mind you may need to match the composer.json file https://github.com/Artem-Schander/L5Modular